# Bookmarklet to add a parameter at end of each URL

Tags: javascript, regex, bookmarklet

I'm trying to have a simple bookmarklet which adds a short parameter at end of any URL

I use ?clearcache to empty an internal cache, so in order not to type it each time, I'm looking for a simple solution

My site is

```
http://subdomain.mysite.net/
```

and with the bookmarklet I want to make the URL go to

```
http://subdomain.mysite.net/?clearcache
```

Same with deeper pages, as I would like it to go to

```
http://subdomain.mysite.net/some-page/?clearcache
```

I'm currently trying with

```
javascript:location=location.href.replace(/http:/g,"/?clearcache")
```

but it isn't working

When I click on that bookmarklet, my URL becomes

```
http://subdomain.mysite.net/?clearcache//subdomain.mysite.net/
```

I feel I am close to it, but I just need a small tip from experts.
I hope for a a reply.
Thanks

Comment: In case someone would like to REPLACE parameters and ended up on this question, the solution would be simple: `javascript:void((function(){window.location.search="?clearcache";})());`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should solve your problem:

**Code**

`javascript:void((function(){var loc = location.href; loc.indexOf("?") == -1 ? (location.href = loc+"?clearcache") : (location.href = loc+"&clearcache");})());`

**Explanation**

Check if any other query string parameters exists. If yes, then appends `clearcache` at the end using an `&` or append to the URL using `?`.

Comment: Thank you.  

    I used a simpler version which seems to work on my case. It was just in front of my nose and I missed it  


    `javascript:location=location.href.replace(location.href,"?clearcache")`  

    I checked HTTP headers and the URL had the ?clearcache at the end. I hope it helps others too

Comment: Before adding the parameter, it is better to check that it's not already in the URL. This modified version would do that: `javascript:void((function(){var loc = location.href; if (loc.indexOf('clearcache') >= 0) return; loc.indexOf("?") < 0 ? (location.href = loc+"?clearcache") : (location.href = loc+"&clearcache");})());`

Comment: Thank you all three of you. I took @valdroni simplest version

Answer (score 1):

Building on [Vikram Deshmukh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20678352) here is a version that uses a varying cache-busting parameter and replaces it every time it is used.

Expanded version:

```js
javascript:void((function () {
    'use strict';
    let href;
    if (document.location.search === '') {
        href = document.location.href + '?_=' + Date.now();
    } else {
        let params = new URLSearchParams(document.location.search.substring(1));
        if (params.get('_') === null) {
            href = document.location.href + '&_=' + Date.now();
        } else {
            params.set('_', Date.now());
            href= document.location.href.substring(0, document.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1) + params.toString();
        }
    }
    document.location.assign(href);
})());
```

Compact version:

```js
javascript:void((function () { let href; if (document.location.search === '') { href = document.location.href + '?_=' + Date.now(); } else { let params = new URLSearchParams(document.location.search.substring(1)); if (params.get('_') === null) { href = document.location.href + '&_=' + Date.now(); } else { params.set('_', Date.now()); href= document.location.href.substring(0, document.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1) + params.toString(); } } document.location.assign(href); })());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a useful answer for those wondering how to do this for 'mod_pagespeed', totally inspired by the above answers.

```
javascript:void((function(){var loc = location.href; if (loc.indexOf('PageSpeed') >= 0) return; loc.indexOf("?") < 0 ? (location.href = loc+"?PageSpeed=off") : (location.href = loc+"&PageSpeed=off");})());
```

Answer (score 0):

Shorter version

```js
javascript:((param = 'yourParam=yourValue') => {const loc = location.href; if (loc.contains(param)) return; location.href = loc + (loc.contains('?') ? '&' : '?') + param})()
```

Tested here and works but apparently doesn't work on some websites that use older JS like amazon.com. Here's compatible version:

```js
javascript:(function (param = 'yourParam=yourValue') {var loc = location.href; if (loc.indexOf(param) > 0) return; location.href = loc + (loc.indexOf('?') > 0 ? '&' : '?') + param})()
```